# SQL Deleted.* Into - Specifying Multiple Columns instead of Naming them

Tags: sql, sql-insert, sql-delete

I am trying to avoid specifying each Column to add to the into piece of the Statement. Is there a way to do this without listing all 100+ columns?

```
Delete From OriginTable
Output Deleted.*
Into NewTable (Deleted.Col1, Deleted.Col2, Deleted.Col3)
Where ConditionsHere
```

The closest I have found is selecting the columns from the sys.col schema selection where it matches the table name. Is there a better way to do this or can I specify Deleted.* somehow in the into line statement. Many sources I found only specify selecting specific columns

Comment: **No** - you need to explicitly list all columns - no way around that.